# Problem with response times in CUDA why cpu is faster than gpu?

Tags: cuda

Hi i have a problem with the time response I am getting a longer response time on GPU than CPU
the algorithm used is a matrix multiplication algorithm

using the next functions:

```
// Start timers
cudaEvent_t timer1, timer2;
cudaEventCreate(&timer1);
cudaEventCreate(&timer2);
cudaEventRecord(timer1, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(timer1);

// Stop timers
    cudaEventRecord(timer2, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timer1);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timer2);
    float elapsed;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, timer1, timer2);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return elapsed;
```

here is my code on GPU:

```
float Mult_gpu(float* hostPtr, float* hostPtr2, float* hostPtr3, int size, int Ncols, int Nrows, int n) {
size_t pitch;

check("Creating timers");
cudaEvent_t timer1, timer2;
cudaEventCreate(&timer1);
cudaEventCreate(&timer2);
cudaEventRecord(timer1, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(timer1);

/******************************************/
/***Configuracion de las matrices en gpu***/
/******************************************/
float* devPtr;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch, n * sizeof(float), Nrows);
cudaMemcpy2D(devPtr, pitch, hostPtr, n * sizeof(float), n * sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

float* devPtr2;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr2, &pitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), n);
cudaMemcpy2D(devPtr2, pitch, hostPtr2, Ncols * sizeof(float), Ncols * sizeof(float), n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

float* devPtr3;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr3, &pitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows);

//dim3 gridSize(iDivUp(Ncols3, BLOCKSIZE_x), iDivUp(Nrows3, BLOCKSIZE_y));
//dim3 blockSize(BLOCKSIZE_y, BLOCKSIZE_x);
dim3 block(32, 32);                                                     //hilos por bloque
dim3 grid((size / block.x) + 1, (size / block.y) + 1);                  //numero de bloques

/**************************/
/**Lanzamiento del kernel**/
/**************************/

Mult << <grid, block >> > (devPtr, devPtr2, devPtr3, pitch, Ncols, Nrows, n);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

/*********************************/
/***Copiado de devPtr a hosPtr2***/
/*********************************/
cudaMemcpy2D(hostPtr3, Ncols * sizeof(float), devPtr3, pitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
//cudaMemcpy(hostPtr3, devPtr3, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(devPtr);
cudaFree(devPtr2);
cudaFree(devPtr3);
// Stop timers
cudaEventRecord(timer2, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(timer1);
cudaEventSynchronize(timer2);
float elapsed;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, timer1, timer2);

cudaDeviceReset();
return elapsed;
```

}

and here is my code on CPU

```
   float Mult_cpu(float* hostPtrA, float* HostPtrB, float* hostPtrC, int Ncols, int Nrows, int n)
{
    cudaEvent_t timer1, timer2;
    cudaEventCreate(&timer1);
    cudaEventCreate(&timer2);
    cudaEventRecord(timer1, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timer1);

    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Ncols; ++j) {
            float suma = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                suma += hostPtrA[i * n + k] * HostPtrB[k * Ncols + j];
            }
            hostPtrC[i * Ncols + j] = suma;

        }
    }

    // Stop timers
    cudaEventRecord(timer2, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timer1);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timer2);
    float elapsed;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, timer1, timer2);

        return elapsed;
    }
```

when i use a matrix 500x500 or any matrix the CPU is faster than GPU and i don't understand why i don't know if the problem is my kernel program or the CUDA functions that im using

my kernel code

```
__global__ void Mult(float* devPtrA, float* devPtrB, float* devPtrC, size_t pitch, int Ncols, int Nrows, int n)
{
    float temp;

    int r = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;      //for (int f = 0; f <= fil - 1; f += 1) equivalencia en for
    int c = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;      //for (int c = 0; c <= col - 1; c += 1)
    if ((r < Ncols) && (c < Nrows)) {
        for (int c2 = 0; c2 < n; c2++) {
            float* vertical = (float*)((char*)devPtrA + r * pitch);
            float element1 = vertical[c2];
            float* horizontal = (float*)((char*)devPtrB + c2 * pitch);
            float element2 = horizontal[c];
            temp += element1 * element2;
        }


        //printf("\nla fila es: %d la columna es: %d el valor es: %8.4f\n\n", r, c, temp);
        float* vertical2 = (float*)((char*)devPtrC + r * pitch);
        vertical2[c] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the GPU automatically be faster than your CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read on the concept of [SIMT architecture, CUDA execution model and branch divergence](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture). Analyze your CUDA kernel performance with a [profiler](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#visual). I suspect that the condition `if ((r < Ncols) && (c < Nrows))` in your kernel causes threads in each warp to diverge and hence the reduced performance. Also `pitch` affects the global memory access pattern in your code which is another factor in the performance of CUDA kernels. Some other excellent optimization tips can be found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#optimizing-cuda-applications).

Answer (score 0):

CudaMalloc is really slow. If you know the size of your matrices beforehand, do the initialization at the beginning of your program.